# How can I add highlighting to checkbox label?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, label, syntax-highlighting

I have a checkbox like the one below, and I'd like to add  font style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: yellow" once the checkbox is clicked.  How would I do this?

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "checkbox" id="prime">
<label for="checkbox" name="checkboxlabel" id="primelabel">Checkbox</label>
```

Comment: your `for` should be equal to your checkbox `id`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name ="prime" id="prime">
<label for="prime" name="checkboxlabel" id="primelabel">Checkbox</label>​
```

**JS**

```
if($("#prime").is(":checked"))
    $('label[for="prime"]').addClass("highlight");

$("#prime").change(function() {
    $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]').toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight { background-color: yellow; }​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YN9aK/3/) | Slightly longer but possibly less likely to cause any issues: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YN9aK/1/)

Comment: Even though there is `id` for label defined - I'd better select it using `label[for="' + this.id + '"]`

Comment: i would use the `change` event. don't know if there's another possability to change the value of a checkbox than a click, but it i think it's the safer way

Comment: Both of you make valid points. I've edited my answer with those changes. Thanks!

Comment: You won't need if statement if you just use toggleClass() with the change function

Comment: @wirey: you don't know the initial checkbox state

Comment: well I'm sure it's easy enough to set it to checked with class as highlight.  Just saying code looks better shorter.  Plus if initial state was Checked.. it wouldn't be highlighted

Comment: @wirey yeah you're right. I updated it to highlight it if the initial state is checked and then use `toggleClass()` as you suggested.

Comment: @sachleen: it still may fail if the checkbox state is changed by js (not by user) - http://jsfiddle.net/t5pAe/. So personally I'd go with the solution with `if`

Comment: Awesome, I've got it up and running.  Thanks.